# After how long are deleted posts really deleted from the system?

Tags: support, deleted-posts

I can find my deleted questions and answers provided I have enough rep on a site.

Would they always be on the site for me to undelete? Or, does the system purge such posts time to time? If yes, what are the schedules of such purges?

Answer (score 18):

Content is never hard deleted unless an SE employee explicitly accesses the database and wipes out the data, which they would not ever do for any reason.

The content stays around forever.

Comment: @animuson but you do hard delete any posts made by underage users, no? (So the answer is still misleading)

Comment: @Shadow We don't delete posts made by underage users at all.